# Get/Set datepicker value

Tags: extjs, extjs4

It might be a silly question but I didn't find a way to get or set value of  `'Ext.form.field.Date'` control. `getValue()` returns null, `setValue()` does nothing.
Where can be mistake?

```
var filterFrom = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
    xtype: 'datefield',
    id: 'From',
    name: 'From'
});

// ...

filterFrom.getValue(); // null
```

If declare `change` listener for picker, it fires on `setValue()` call, but nothing changes on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filterFrom.setValue(new Date());
filterFrom.getValue();
> Date {Tue Feb 14 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100}
filterFrom.setValue(new Date('December 19, 1989 03:24:00'));
filterFrom.getValue();
> Date {Tue Dec 19 1989 00:00:00 GMT+0100}
```

These work for me with your code (I just added a misssing `)` after `}` in line 5.

Comment: `)` is not a problem, just bad copy-pasting

Comment: That's what I assumed. Anyway, to work woth datepicker you should use `Date` objects and everything should work fine.

Comment: The matter is even I set the date on UI, the I can't get it with `getValue()`

Comment: So, the problem has no place in case single picker are placed on page, but reproduces with all the other controls. Can it be some kind of intersection with the other controls?

Comment: Might be. It's quite easy to lose track of components when there are many of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it in the configs:

```
           {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                id: 'assessField',
                fieldLabel: 'Assessment Date',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                labelWidth: 125,
                width: 240,
                value: new Date(),
                minValue: '01/01/2012',
                maxValue: '08/15/2012'
            }
```

Comment: Setting the minValue and maxValue is the best way to go. Great comment the_skua.